# Simple Git works when tested singularly but doesn't work when used in a larger project Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, git

I have a very simple js git code that doesn't seem to work. It sometimes pushes random commits, but for most of the commits, it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```js
const jsonfile = require("jsonfile");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const chalk = require("chalk");
const ora = require("ora");
const boxen = require("boxen");

const simpleGit = require("simple-git");

const FILE_PATH = "./data.json";

function daysIntoYear(){
  let date = new Date();
  return (Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()) - Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), 0, 0)) / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000;
}

const makeCommit = (DATE, n) => {
  if (n === 0) return simpleGit().push();
  const data = {
    date: DATE,
    iter: n
  };

  d = new Date(DATE);

  var curr_date = d.getDate();
  var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
  // Log for debugging purposes
  // console.log(curr_month + "-" + curr_date + "-" + curr_year);
  
  jsonfile.writeFile(FILE_PATH, data, () => {
    simpleGit()
      .add([FILE_PATH])
      .commit(crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex'), ['--date=' + d])
      .push();
  });

  makeCommit(DATE, --n)
};

function getRandomCommits () {
  let result = crypto.randomInt(0, 101)

  if (result <= 30) {
    return crypto.randomInt(0, 6)
  } else if (result <= 45) {
    return crypto.randomInt(0, 14)
  } else {
    return crypto.randomInt(0, 25)
  }
}

function commitsAndContributions () {
  let iter = daysIntoYear();
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
    result.push({
      date: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, i),
      commits: getRandomCommits()
    })
  }
  result.splice(0, 1)
  return result;
}

function startCommits () {
  let data = commitsAndContributions();
  const spinner = ora("Generating your GitHub activity\n").start();
  fs.writeFileSync('./commits.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    makeCommit(data[i].date, data[i].commits);
  }
  spinner.succeed();

  console.log(
    boxen(
      `${chalk.green("Success!")} ${
        data.length
      } commits have been created.`,
      { borderColor: "yellow", padding: 1, align: "center" }
    )
  );
}

startCommits()
```

`Data.json` is an actual file, `commits.json` is also a file, and this is linked to a github repo. When I run the script:

```js
  jsonfile.writeFile('./data.json', new Date(), () => {
    simpleGit()
      .add(['./data.json'])
      .commit(crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex'), ['--date=' + new Date()])
      .push();
  });
```

I can see the random commit get pushed. However, it doesn't work when I run the main script. Is there a reason for this?

---

Edit: As far as I can tell, it pushes one commit, and ignores the rest. Is there some sort of ratelimit going on?

Answer (score 0):

The loop in `startCommits` runs synchronously (ie: doesn't wait for the commit/push to finish before carrying on to the next iteration). You will therefore likely see a success message before anything more than the first commit has been started.

In this example the `makeCommit` and `startCommits` functions are changed to be `async` with each entry in the `data` array processed in full before the next one is begun:

```js
const {writeFile} = require('fs/promises');

const makeCommit = async (DATE, n) => {
  if (n === 0) return simpleGit().push();

  const data = {
    date: DATE,
    iter: n
  };

  d = new Date(DATE);

  await writeFile(FILE_PATH, 'utf8', JSON.stringify(data));
  await simpleGit()
      .add([FILE_PATH])
      .commit(crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex'), ['--date=' + d])
      .push();
  });

  makeCommit(DATE, --n)
};


async function startCommits () {
  let data = commitsAndContributions();
  const spinner = ora("Generating your GitHub activity\n").start();
  fs.writeFileSync('./commits.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))

  for (const entry of data) {
    await makeCommit(entry.date, entry.commits);
  }

  spinner.succeed();
}
```